# How to add sql "BETWEEN" conditions inside CASE within WHERE CLAUSE in SQL

Tags: sql, case, where-clause, between

I have a sql query where I need to add different statements(between statements) in where clause based on one condition.  If TX.APPLICATION_ID is 'CONV' then I need to add filter date range on SYS_CREATION_DATE and if APPLICATION_ID is not 'CONV' then I need to add filter date range on TRANS_DATE. Here is what i'm trying and getting 'missing keyword' error. please suggest

```
WHERE TX.TRANS_TYPE IN ('CREDIT', 'CREDITR','CREDITR9', 'DSPJUS')  
  AND 
    CASE
    WHEN TRIM(TX.APPLICATION_ID) = 'CONV' 
    THEN 
      TX.SYS_CREATION_DATE  BETWEEN  TO_DATE('20200831', 'YYYYMMDD')  AND  TO_DATE('20200831', 'YYYYMMDD')
    ELSE 
       TX.TRANS_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('20200831', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20200831', 'YYYYMMDD')
    END
```

Comment: Don't think `CASE`. Just try composing your conditions together using boolean logic, AND, OR, NOT. You cannot use `CASE` to suddenly substitute in arbitrary parts of a statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `CASE` expression logic, which generally never belongs in the `WHERE` clause.  Instead, use vanilla `AND`/`OR`:

```sql
WHERE
    TX.TRANS_TYPE IN ('CREDIT', 'CREDITR','CREDITR9', 'DSPJUS') AND (
    (
        TRIM(TX.APPLICATION_ID) = 'CONV' AND
        TX.SYS_CREATION_DATE >= date '20200831' AND
        TX.SYS_CREATION_DATE < date '20200901'
    )
    OR
    (
        TRIM(TX.APPLICATION_ID) <> 'CONV' AND
        TX.TRANS_DATE >= date '20200831' AND
        TX.TRANS_DATE < date '20200901'
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. This syntax working :) 
But could you please suggest is it not good practice to use case in where clause ?

Comment: @Venkat Well `CASE` expressions are intended for generating new values from a given input value.  So, the general use case is you feed in some column value, and get out multiple possible values.  In the `WHERE` clause, you mainly want to check logical conditions, rather than generating new values.

Comment: @Venkat . . . `case` expressions enforce the order of evaluation.  This impeded the optimizer which is often focused on the filtering in the `where` clause.